# Diff() between two collections in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, diff

I have done research. I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but the solutions in other questions were not really my fit, and thus, I made a new question.

What is the best way with Javascript to compare two collections?

I have thousands of these headers in this Mongo document format:

```
{
    "url": "google.com",
    "headers": {
        "location": "http://www.google.com/",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        "date": "Mon, 25 Mar 2013 18:12:08 GMT",
        "expires": "Wed, 24 Apr 2013 18:12:08 GMT",
        "cache-control": "public, max-age=2592000",
        "server": "gws",
        "content-length": "219",
        "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
        "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN"
    }
}
```

I ran my scraper today. I would, in the future, run it again, and store that in a second collection. Additionally, I would like to be able to compare three specific header objects, and that is `server`, `x-aspnet-version`, and `x-powered-by`, and detect if there are any integer increments.

What is the best way to iterate through two collections and do a diff()?

Am I doing it right? Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please add some extra details to your question: I don't understand what you're comparing exactly. Every document from one collection and every document of the other collection?  How often and how many documents? Does performance matter (if so, how much)? What have you tried (you should post what you've tried)?

Comment: I would like to, for each URL, compare `server` `x-aspnet-version` `x-powered-by` in bi-monthly increments. `server` often outputs information like Microsoft-IIS/7.0, Apache versions, and/or nginx. I would like to detect whether or not there were any changes from these bi-monthly scans.

Comment: Show us the code you tried. This sounds like it will need to be very brute force. My only recommendation is to use `each` with a smaller batch size rather than `toArray`. http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html  Or, use `nextObject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

You could use a combination of url and the date accessed (at least part of the datetime object) as the _id for these objects since from what I can tell you plan to scrape each url once a month.

Example:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "date": ISODate("2013-03-01"),
    },
    // Other attributes
}
```

This yields performance, uniqueness, and query dividends (see [this 4sq blog post](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/02/09/mongodb-strategies-for-the-disk-averse/)). You could query doing something like:

```
db.collection.find({
    "_id": {
        "$gte": {
            "url": yourUrl,
            "date": rangeStart
         },
         "$lt": {
            "url": yourUrl,
            "date": rangeEnd
         },
    }
})
```

Which yields excellent, nicely sorted (by url THEN by date, which seems to be just what you want) results. You could also use this index to perform covered queries (over the _id field) if you just want a nice set of all of the urls and months you have scraped (this could set you up nicely to go through each url one at a time).

If you have specific attributes of the document that you're interested in comparing (`headers.server` for example) and a specific comparison you want to do for them (looking for any increment in version numbers for example), I would use some kind of regex to grab the elements relevant to version number (a quick and dirty one might simply retrieve all numeric elements) and graph them for each url (I assume this would let you visualize changes to server software over time). You could just as easily report whenever any of these attributes changed by scanning them in order and setting off some event when the strings were not identical (perhaps then reporting the change or the numerical piece of the change).

Comment: Hi marr75. Thank you for your input. I have changed up my scraped headers, and they are now in the format of `url`, `date`, `server`, `x-aspnet-version`, `x-powered-by`. Is there anyway for there to be purely numerical dates? The date used now is very hard to take apart, if that's the correct way to say it. My goal is to set a time frame in-between, and compare `server` to `server`, `x-aspnet-version` to `x-aspnet-version`, and `x-powered-by`.

Comment: I like the look of the second version of your example. What you are trying to achieve is us `$lt` and `$gt` to set a date range, right? But how would I advance with this example? For example, should I scrape two collections, with the first and second collection being months apart? I have heard I should use one collection, but that means I will have to re-engineer my scraper's code, which I might not be able to because of time constraints. I am happy for your realization of "by url THEN by date THEN by the other variables". That is precisely what I wanted to do.

Comment: But maybe we could ignore the `date` as a header and instead just compare two collections?

Comment: Your first code example gave me a realization too. My attempt (in code) to ensureIndex my URL failed. `db.scrape.ensureIndex("url",function(e){
  console.log("Error while indexing");
});`

Comment: When you give a newbie a keyboard, an idea, and an editor, bad things tend to happen :P

Comment: `ISODate("2013-03-01")` will actually store (and compare) in a numerical format, you can look up BSON data types if you need more details (you probably don't right now). Anyway, month or date or whatever you want to call the attribute as a datetime will allow the range queries you're looking for.

Comment: The "second version" is just an example query you might do against documents with the `_id` field I described to you. You can add a sort that will do by url by date but it may be more computationally expensive. As for "re-engineering" the scraper's code, it seems like you would just have to replace the code segment where you calculate the collection name you'll be inserting to and make it a constant.

Comment: Comparing two collections requires that you create a context for the comparison. For example, if you're diffing two text documents, this context will frequently be line numbers. You're comparing a set of documents that should, within your existing setup, be uniquely identified by their url attribute. Your differencing logic should be as simple as sorting each collection by url and then comparing the keys list of each document, noting any differences before noting the value of each identical key and reporting value differences.