# Scanning Mongo databases with Javascript and setting off events when strings are not identical

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to work on a Javascript algorithm to loop through my MongoDB, search for two identifical URLs, and do an analysis of the header objects.

Below is a snippet of an example of this object:

```
{
    "url": "www.professionalsupplementcenter.com",
    "date": "Tue Mar 26 2013 15:08:31 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
    "headers": {
        "server": "Microsoft-IIS/7.5",
        "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
        "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET"
    }
}
```

Specifically, I will have two collections. The two collections are two databases in MongoDB of HTTP header scrapes two months apart. Let's call them `todayScrape` and `twoMonthFromNowScrape`. Through these two collections, I want to compare their header objects, so, `server`, `x-aspnet-version`, and `x-powered-by` and see if there has been any upgrades within these numbers, E.G. `IIS/7.5` upgraded to `IIS/8.0` (in the future).

I do not have any code to display, because I don't know how to implement this system at all. I have no idea where to begin. I want to first compare the two URLs, then when the program identified that both URLs exist, it would then do a specific comparison of the three header objects. It could then report whenever these attributes are changed by scanning them in order and set off some event like `console.log("There has been a change")` when the strings are not identical.

Can anyone give me any suggestions on where to begin? I have been stuck on this issue a couple days and being stuck has been disheartening. I would really like to begin implementing it, but I need some assistance.

Comment: This is the same question you asked before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621883/diff-between-two-collections-in-mongodb

Comment: Yessir. I did not phrase my question properly last time, therefore I was not able to properly express what I was trying to propose.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is too broad, and SO community mostly deal with actual code-challenges rather than with abstract and consultancy-nature questions.
Although I would recommend you to put everything in one collection and then use aggregations to group by `url` key and sort data inside, and get nice results of out good aggregate query so you can then analyse data and make your next logical decisions.

Comment: This is a very old question with an accepted answer...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need is `npm install mongodb` (if you haven't already). Then in your app.js file:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var Server = mongodb.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {});
new mongodb.Db('scraperapp', Server, {w: 1}).open(function(err, db){
  var scrape = new mongodb.Collection(db, 'scrape');
  var scrapeFuture = new mongodb.Collection(db, 'scrapeFuture');
  scrape.find({url: {$exists: true}}).toArray(function(err, today_docs){
    if(!today_docs) return;
    var scrapeFn = function(i){
      var today_doc = today_docs[i];
      scrapeFuture.findOne({url: today_doc.url}, function(err, future_doc){
        if(!future_doc) return;
        if(today_doc.headers.server != future_doc.headers.server)
          console.log(today_doc.url + ':servers different');
        if(today_doc.headers['x-aspnet-version'] != future_doc.headers['x-aspnet-version'])
          console.log(today_doc.url + ':x-aspnet-versions different');
        if(today_doc.headers['x-powered-by'] != future_doc.headers['x-powered-by'])
          console.log(today_doc.url + ':x-powered-by different');
        if(today_docs[i+1]) scrapeFn(i+1);
      });
    }
    scrapeFn(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your code. I wanted to thank you first before I try. Could I keep you updated with my progress? I already have my MongoDB setup, and I have the two collections of headers. The part in which I am stuck in was the use of logic to find the attributes that are not identical.

Comment: Are there any differences I need to make to your code if I have two collections already, and one is called `scrape` and the other is called `scrapeFuture`? The code I have currently uses `var dburl = 'localhost/scraperapp';
var collections = ['scrapeFuture'];
var db = require('mongojs').connect(dburl, collections);`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - Yeah if you already have access to the collections, then you can just replace `today_scrape` and `2month_scrape` with your variables and only include the code starting from `today_scrape.find({url: ....` and ending with the appropriate `});`

Comment: Can you explain to me what `today_docs` and `2month_doc` does? It does not seem like it's parallel to the rest of the code. Does it mean `today_scrape` and `2month_scrape`? Thank you.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - After mongodb finds documents, it passes them to the callback function which we are writing inline. You can name them whatever you want, but `today_docs` are all of the documents from `today_scrape` that have a URL. `2month_doc` is a document from `2month_scrape` that has the same URL as the current document from `today_docs`. (You can see that we are looping through each of the `today_docs` and then using that to find a match.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26968/discussion-between-thegreencabbage-and-aust)

Comment: This user took his own time to help me out in private chat to make this application work. Thank you Aust.. Please give him some upvotes.